# Electron-Redux, Typescript, Redux-Observable and Typed Actions

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-observable

I come from an ngrx background and quite used to the ngrx way of using typed actions.

i.e.

```
export class RestoreWindowState implements FluxStandardAction {
  public readonly type = windowActionTypes.WINDOW_RESTORE_STATE;

  constructor(public payload: IWindowState) {}
}
```

where FluxStandardAction Looks like this

```
export interface FluxStandardAction {
  type: string;
  payload?: any;
  error?: boolean;
  meta?: any;
}
```

I wrote a custom middleware to convert `new windowActions.RestoreWindowState(state)` to a plain object. Here is what my middleware looks like.

```
export const actionToPlainObjectMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (typeof action === 'object' && action.type) {
    const toForward = { ...action };
    return next(toForward);
  } else {
    throw new Error('Action must be FSA');
  }
};
```

now if i do

```
const loadWindowStateFromStorageEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(windowActionTypes.WINDOW_LOAD_STATE_FROM_STORAGE).pipe(
    mapTo(() => {
      const windowState = WindowStateKeeper.load('main');
      return new windowActions.RestoreWindowState(windowState);
    }),
  );
```

i get

`Error: Action must be FSA`

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Since your custom middleware is throwing the `Action must be FSA` error, when its reached what was actually dispatched? e.g. what does action equal?

Comment: i was getting a function at the point where my custom middleware was throwing the error. so i refactored it to https://gist.github.com/ysfjwd/23b3c262831b921f239610ec3a5b4bf5 and it started working, but this is strange.

Comment: updated gist to contain more info.

Comment: also, have asked the same question at https://github.com/hardchor/electron-redux/issues/82 with a little more detail.

Comment: Found the issue! hehe added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `mapTo` instead of `map`. `mapTo` takes a single argument, which is the value as-is that you want to map to. Whereas `map` take a projection function which is called and used to map the current value to some other value--which is what you're intending.

```
// v--------- here
mapTo(() => {
  const windowState = WindowStateKeeper.load('main');
  return new windowActions.RestoreWindowState(windowState);
})

// change to
map(() => {
  const windowState = WindowStateKeeper.load('main');
  return new windowActions.RestoreWindowState(windowState);
})
```

So in this case you were mapping the action to the function, and that function is what was being dispatched as-is.